# How do you get a container (ie grid) to fit the rotated size of its content?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

(Windows 8.1, Windows Store App)

I'd like to put rotated text in a container (eg. Grid) and have that container get its dimensions from the rotated text. However...

This code:

```
<Canvas Background="Gray">

    <Grid
        Canvas.Left="100"
        Canvas.Top="100"
        Background="LightGray">
        <TextBlock Text="Text rotated 270º">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>

<Canvas>
```

...renders like this:

[image]

I expected the grid to take it's width and height from the TextBlock after rotation was applied. However, it appears the grid takes its dimensions from the TextBlock before rotation is applied.

How do you get a container (ie grid) to fit the rotated size of its content (ie TextBlock)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a LayoutTransform. Here is a great [blog post](http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/) on how you can achieve this in Windows 8.

Looks like [this toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) from cookplex already has one baked in! You can use the [LayoutTransformControl](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/LayoutTransformControl.cs). This toolkit is available through [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit/).

You add it as content of a control, and place your content within it.

```
<Grid
    Canvas.Left="100"
    Canvas.Top="100"
    Background="LightGray">
    <controls:LayoutTransformControl x:Name="transformControl">
        <controls:LayoutTransformControl.Transform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" Angle="270"/>
        </controls:LayoutTransformControl.Transform>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello LayoutTransformControl" />
    </controls:LayoutTransformControl>
 </Border>
```